# Virtue Mart Joomla

Tags: joomla, e-commerce, virtuemart

I have my shop showing this URL when a user checks out.
index.php?page=checkout.index&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=65&redirected=1&Itemid=65

for all the steps it does not show the checkoout_stage as i would expect below in the URL hence it ends up using the home template with the layout distorted

What i expect instead:
index.php?page=checkout.index&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=65&redirected=1&Itemid=65&checkout_stage=1
index.php?page=checkout.index&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=65&redirected=1&Itemid=65&checkout_stage=2
index.php?page=checkout.index&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=65&redirected=1&Itemid=65&checkout_stage=3
index.php?page=checkout.index&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=65&redirected=1&Itemid=65&checkout_stage=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common mistake that will give you this type of problem is not having a menu item for Virtuemat or the VM module published somewhere. You have to have a menu item for VM, even if its in a hidden menu, same with the VM module. Even if you put it in a hidden position you still have to have one and it needs to be published.

If that doesn't do it, we need a lot more information before we can help.

Comment: The Component is not showing in the menu type when i want to create a menu item. How do I manually make the component to show.Thanks

Comment: How did you install it? Menu types show up based on the views available in the enabled components. If VM is installed properly it should just be there.

Comment: When you installed it, did you run all of the SQL files in the VM install?

Comment: i followed instructions for manual install so i was hoping that part was automated.